# How to set default 'first' value in resolver

Tags: django, graphene-python

I have the following snippet:

```
def resolve_products(self, info, **kwargs):
    return Product.objects.all()
```

I want to return 100 results by default. I notice that if I specify say first: 30 in my query

```
{ products (first: 30 ){} }
```

that `first` appears in `kwargs`.

I then tried setting `kwargs['first']` to 100 if no `first` key is found, but it has no effect.

How do I default `first` so all results do not get returned by default?

Comment: Are you using Django?

Comment: Yes, I am using Django 2

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like

```
def resolve_products(self, info, **kwargs):
    limit = int(kwargs.get("first",100))
    return Product.objects.all()[:limit]
```